# How to harmonize ^1 ^2 ^3 with VI V i in minor

Tags: theory, chords, voice-leading, chord-voicings

[image]

I tried my best to harmonize this in minor and the best I could come up with was a VI without a 5th and a doubled 3rd. I am not sure if this is right. And did I write the doubled F correctly in the VI chord?

Comment: Is there not an answer section in the exercises for all the questions you're asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the VI chord is a really tricky one. Especially in minor, *every single voice* has a possible error: either parallel fifths, parallel octaves, or an augmented second.

In general, that VI chord, when it either moves to V or comes after V, is going to have a doubled chordal third. You did this perfectly.

But also, whenever you're moving to a V chord, you don't want to have a doubled scale-degree 6 (this includes predominant chords like iv and ii°). This is because one of those scale-degree 6s must go down to 5, meaning that if it's doubled, your other scale-degree 6 must either also go down to 5 (and create parallel octaves), or go up to 7 (and have an augmented second). And neither of those is good!

And so one of these is exactly what you have in your tenor: do you see how it moves from D♭ to C, just like the bass? So you've got parallel octaves here that we want to fix.

The good news is that it's an easy fix: just keep the A♭ in the tenor for that VI chord, then jump that A♭ up to C for the V chord. But *definitely* keep that doubled F in the soprano and alto (which is notated perfectly, by the way); that's a must.